# Using a mysql function in an Active Record order clause

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, timezone

I have a table `sessions` with a datetime field `starts_at`. The `starts_at` is stored in UTC, however I want to return the sessions sorted by starts_at in local time and just as a time, not datetime.

So If I have sessions with date times of:

```
s1 Jan 1, 13:00
s2 Jan 2, 11:00
s3 Jan 1, 23:00
```

Without considering time zones I'd want them returned in this order: `s2, s1, s3`.

Now I want to get all utc times in local time because lets say that the time zone in effect adds 2 hours to utc. The order of `s2, s1, s3` would now be wrong. We would want s3, s2, s1.

What I've been trying is:

`Session.order("CONVERT_TZ(starts_at,'UTC', '#{tz}')")`

and

`Session.order("TIME(CONVERT_TZ(starts_at,'UTC', '#{tz}'))")`

Where `tz = Time.now.strftime('%Z')` (before this I also set Time.now.zone to the timezone that all of the sessions will be taking place in)

Unfortunately this has given me odd results that appear to be in no order of any kind.

Answer (score 1):

depends on what your tz is set to...maybe it's invalid..
I was able to do it with explicitly specifying number of hours like this

```
SELECT *,TIME(starts_at),TIME(CONVERT_TZ(TIME(starts_at),'+00:00', '+2:00')) FROM 
sessions
ORDER BY TIME(CONVERT_TZ(TIME(starts_at),'+00:00', '+2:00'))
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1e0ef/8

Comment: Thank you! It looks like passing the strings 'UTC" and 'PDT' was the problem, everything worked fine when I instead passed the number of hours.

Answer (score 1):

So you want to sort these by hour and minute (ignoring the date), but you want to first convert to your local time zone so that the first item is after midnight (local time).

```
Session.order("HOUR(CONVERT_TZ(starts_at, 'UTC', '#{tz}')), MINUTE(starts_at)")
```

You can extract the hour after converting to local time. You can extract the minute part without converting (unless you have fractional time zones).